# How can I configure quality of service configuration for socket.io Python?

Tags: python, socket.io

How can I configure quality of service features (comparable to [MQTT QoS features](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels/)) of the Python implementation of [socket.io](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

**EDIT:** Probably socket.io does not support QoS features at all: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATM there are no QoS features available in socket.io. Refer to the issue for further updates on this.